# append a div that includes php into a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a div with an ID of intro, i want to append a div containing php that will give me data from my database when i clicked a button. i have successfully append `<li>` successfully but when I want to append a div containing php it wont append.

```
<div class="container" id="article">
<button id="addArticle()" onClick="addArticle()">+</button>
    <div class="section" id="intro">
        <?php
        require_once("dbconfig.php");

        $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=1");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        { ?>
            <?php echo $row['content'];  ?> 
        <?php
        } 
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="usage">
        <?php
        require_once("dbconfig.php");

        $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=2");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        { ?>
            <?php echo $row['content'];  ?> 
        <?php
        } 
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Code that I want to append when I click the `+` button:

```
<div class="section" id="intro">
        <?php
        require_once("dbconfig.php");

        $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=8");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        { ?>
            <?php echo $row['content'];  ?> 
        <?php
        } 
        ?>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function addArticle(){
    $('#article').append('<li>tes2</li>');
}
```

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: You can not “append PHP”, PHP is long done and finished by the time you are doing anything on the client side. At most you can append the _output_ a certain piece of PHP code created.

Comment: Maybe take a look at AJAX. Click the button, make an AJAX call (to a server PHP page), then update the `html()` contents of your `intro` div.

Comment: php is no javascript a php file runs once from top to bottom and than its finished. So your only possibility is to call via ajax a php file and write the result to your div

Answer (score 0):

PHP has already done in server side before the page send to you.
In your case, you may try to use AJAX.
I did a simple example for you, but you need to make it fit to your solution.

***view.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showContent()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Name : <span id="paragraph"></span>
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick="showContent()">Show me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

***content.php***

```
<?php
echo "milan";
?>
```

Hope it help ;)